# Cloud Save Download not available for PS5 games

Tags: ps4, ps5

I am playing both PS4 and PS5 games on PS5. Now, I find that in PS4 games, there are both options to Download and Upload Cloud Save from Console to Cloud and vice versa. But this feature is missing in PS5 games. I sometimes would want to reload a previously saved file onto my console. 
Is there any setting that I need to select, to enable both upload and download of cloud save file?

The pictures attached here are examples.
In Bloodborne, which is a PS4 games, you can see that both Download and Upload options exist. But in Final Fantasy VII Remake PS5 version, the Download option is not there.

PS4 Version (Game- Bloodborne)
[image]

PS5 Version (Game- Final Fantasy VII Remake)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it's not as intuitive as it was on PS4.

To **upload** your saves to cloud storage:

- Go to Settings > Saved Data and Game/App Settings
- Select Saved Data (PS5) or Saved Data (PS4)
- Select Console Storage and select a game > Upload to Cloud Storage.

To **download** your saves from cloud storage:

- Go to Settings > Saved Data and Game/App Settings.
- Select Saved Data (PS5) or Saved Data (PS4).
- Select Cloud Storage and select a game > Download to Console Storage.

You can find more info in [this article](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/subscriptions/ps5-ps-plus-cloud-storage/).